# How do I get my text to wrap inside of my dijit.form.select

Tags: css, select, dojo, html-table

I am using a dijit.form.select on my page.  When I inspect this widget in the browser, I can see that it is actually made up of a table and tr and td elements.  I am struggling to get my text to wrap inside of the dropdown if the option chosen extends beyond the max-width. I have tried setting a max-width on the span that contains the text, but the text still extends beyond the element.  I have done several searches for a solution with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide CSS for the dijitSelectLabel section. Here is an example of how to set it to a fixed width of 90px;

```
.dijitSelect .dijitButtonContents .dijitButtonText .dijitSelectLabel {
    width: 90px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```